# Can't login into Titanium Studio (and can't migrate to the next IDE)

Tags: macos, authentication, titanium, appcelerator

I can't migrate to Appcelerator Studio and I'm still using Titanium Studio. But this morning, when I tried to login, I got the following error:

```
Last login: Sat Jul 25 09:58:13 on ttys001
iMac-di-mooo:~ mooo$ /Applications/Titanium\ Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/TitaniumStudio ; exit;
!SESSION 2015-07-25 10:00:17.168 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_EN
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/mooo/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/mooo/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-07-25 10:00:18.561
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
logout
```

I googled a little and found this error is quite common in Titanium Studio, Eclipse and NetBeans too. But, even if I tried anything [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Errors_Logging_In_to_Studio) I could not make it work the way it worked just yesterday.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on windows. I suspect its related to a recently installed java update (Sun 8.51) that I installed in the last few days.

Comment: After following the instructions at your link, I was able to use the InstallCert to get mine up and running. Thanks!

Comment: No, it didn't work for me  :-(  I'm glad I could help, anyway